# java string index out of bound exception

Tags: java

It seems like a simple question but I'm wondering why if I had some String variable like this:

```
String name = "John";
```

And then I'm using the substring method like this :

```
System.out.print(name.substring(3,4));
```

it works fine but if i'd change 4 for 5 or higher I get `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. But as i understand indexes correct there is no 4 index as well but the outpul will be `"n"`

```
J O H N
0 1 2 3
```

Could someone explain such behavior? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It has 4 as endIndex, meaning it will take the chars starting from the beginIndex (3) up to (so, exclusive) the endIndex.

Comment: Reading [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) helps sometimes ...

Answer (score 7):

The second parameter to `substring` is an *exclusive* upper bound - so it's allowed to be equal to the length of the string, in order to include the last character. Likewise it makes sense to allow the starting point to be "at" the end of the string, so long as the end is equal to the start, yielding an empty string.

Basically, for APIs which deal with ranges, it often makes sense to think of the indexes as being "between" characters rather than "on" them. For example:

```
  J O H N
 ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
 0 1 2 3 4
```

Both indexes have to be within the range shown, and the `endIndex` index must be either the same as `beginIndex` or to the right - then the substring is the characters between the two corresponding boundaries:

```
"JOHN".substring(1, 3) is "OH"

  J O H N
   ^ ^ ^
   1   3
```

This is exactly as [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-), of course

> `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the `beginIndex` is negative, or `endIndex` is larger than the length of this String object, or `beginIndex` is larger than `endIndex`.

Comment: Nice way of thinking characters indexes!

Answer (score 1):

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int):

> Throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if the beginIndex is negative, or
>   **endIndex is larger than the length of this String object**, or
>   beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

You string's length is 4, so 4 is OK but 5 or more is KO.

Answer (score 0):

**substring(a,b)** method of String object returns substring
from index **a to b-1**
so substring(3,4) return only "N" i.e only index value 3.
note that substring(a,a) returns always a null string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missunderstanding this by saying that"there is no 4 index as well but the outpul will be "n"" , the substring method counts from 1(not from 0) so your first example had nothing wrong with it because the fourth character was atually n.